# Do symmetric BJTs exist?

Tags: transistors, bjt

Fundamentally, a BJT is a very thin layer of P (or N) type semiconductor sandwiched between two thicker layers of N (respectively P) type semiconductor. There's nothing intrinsic to that design that would indicate the collector and the emitter have to be physically distinct. Is it possible to make a symmetric BJT, that can operate identically in forward and reverse mode? If so, are any manufactured on a commercial scale?

I understand that making a transistor symmetric would necessarily sacrifice some desirable traits. I don't understand why, or which traits (probably β at least), though; I just know that if there weren't advantages to making them asymmetric, they wouldn't be made asymmetric.

Comment: You can already run a BJT backwards, with a gain of near-but-less-than 1.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm wondering if any exist that have the same gain in both directions.

Comment: I'm also hard-pressed to consider a *use case* for such a device. Symmetrical FETs yes, but nothing comes to mind for BJTs.

Comment: Yeah, and this question is about BJTs because I know that symmetrical FETs do exist. Plenty of JFETs are symmetric, and MOSFETs in ICs often are (though discrete ones are not). So you mean you think the reason symmetric BJTs might not exist is because there's just no reason to make them? I suppose that's a valid enough answer! I am curious if they are possible, though.

Comment: Also, are you sure the gain will be less than one in reverse-active mode? I don't see many sources one way or the other, but they seem to suggest it would be greater than one but quite small compared to the forward-active gain.

Comment: It might be greater. Running them backwards is not something I've studied in depth.

Comment: My first thought was the [UJT, or UniJunction Transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unijunction_transistor). However, it doesn't behave like a conventional BJT. HowHowever, even that, if you read the article, is asymmetric, hence comment rather than answer.

Comment: i have a BC547C here beta is 333 reverse beta is 3, so you can get gain in the reverse direction.  I once built an oscillator with reversed transistors.

Comment: Yeah. It's possible They used to exist when they made alloy-junction and point-contact stuff. As soon as they were able to make them on wafers, all that mostly stopped. I have some here that I got from a company's old untouched basement supplies. Not sure if you can still get them anymore, though. Just look up "alloy-junction" and I think you can find some names, at least. Sziklai wrote a paper in 1953 detailing some of their operational details. RCA made some of the ones I have. https://sites.google.com/site/transistorhistory/Home/us-semiconductor-manufacturers/rca-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out "muting transistors" in consumer audio gear:

http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/toshiba/978.pdf

The purpose of these is to short the outputs of a device to ground, for example while it powers up and down, to avoid producing a THUMP. Since the signal to short out is AC and has a DC component of 0V, a bidirectional switch is needed. MOSFETs would not work because the body diode would chop off half the signal when the switch is open, so the usual suspect here is a BJT, 2SC2878. Q801/Q802 here:

[image]

These are optimized for high reverse hFe and high Vebo (so the base junction doesn't act as a zener when they're off).

Apart from these special perks which make them pretty much the only BJT able to fulfill this role, the rest of their characteristics is very unremarkable.

Comment: I imagine the \$V_{EBO}\$ would also make them pretty nice for Joule Thief applications. The base's transformer coil can have a nasty kick-back voltage which will puncture the BE junction and eventually impair its function. A protection diode can be added, but it wastes battery energy. Might be hard to obtain. The only TO-92 variety I found, the 2SC2878, is pretty much either VERY EXPENSIVE or not in stock. (The 2SC3326 is around, though, but that's SMT.) Not exactly symmetrical construction, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

A group named [Ideal-Power](http://www.idealpower.com/) is developing the [B-Tran](http://www.idealpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Btran-white-paper-CURRENT-12April2016.pdf) and is in the [proto-type](http://www.eenewseurope.com/news/first-double-sided-b-tran-power-devices-built-0) stage I believe.

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the actual layout of these. What are those switches that are shown? Are they external devices? The white paper is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @Felthry. I think the switches are only shown as an indicator of how they are driven. The BTRAN has two bases by the look of it.

Comment: It's hard to know much from those links, I agree. Until they disclose some specific drive circuitry approaches, the question is moot.

Comment: @jonk yup, I just came across then a week or two ago, and though I would share.