# Can Vds ever becomes negative in mosfet?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog

Due to the symmetry in mosfet, source and drain are interchangeable. So we define the source of nmos is the terminal with the lower voltage. So if we force Vds to become negative the drain and source should flip. So Vds becomes positive again.

If that is true then the following is true?

If the overdrive voltage of an nmos is 0.2, for example, and I forced Vds to -0.3 will the mosfet operate in sat with source and drain flipped?

[image]
Here is a circuit from CMOS analog design book by Razavi showing flipping of the drain and source.

Comment: some MOSFETs have special implants at the Drain, to handle high voltages; generic silicon FETs seem to have no special source or drain implants, at least in processes I've used;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. In reality, a MOSFET is a four-terminal device. The body is not necessarily connected to the source. For the planar MOSFETs used in VLSI design the source and drain are physically the same kind of structure.

So, the source of the NMOS transistor is the terminal with the lower voltage, out of the two terminals that could be either source or drain. This behavior is necessary for bidirectional analog multiplexers that use MOS pass transistors.

That means that the answer to your question is **no**, \$V_{DS}\$ cannot be negative, because the more negative terminal is always the source.

Answer (score 0):

You assume the MOSFET is symmetric. This is not the case; real FETs (in discrete devices, anyway; internal to ICs is another matter but not one relevant to anyone not going deep into VLSI design) have the source terminal distinguished by being connected to the body terminal. A true symmetric MOSFET would have four terminals: source, gate, drain, and body/bulk/substrate (no one can seem to agree on the name of the fourth one).

This symbol, which seems to be considered the "most proper" symbol, makes that clearer:

[image: The traditional MOSFET symbol, showing the body terminal connected to the source. This one is missing the body diode though.]

Comment: And usually, there's a built-in diode in that body connection that causes current to flow from source to drain (in an NMOS) or drain to source (in a PMOS) when you get the connections flipped.

Comment: It is not always that case. These mosfets (source connected to bulk) require triple well technology (I don't know how much it is available now), but if you don't have access to triple well technology you have to connect the bulk to ground so in this case it will be symmetic (as you mentioned above).

Comment: @HassanIbrahim Are we talking about internal to ICs? My experience with FETs is almost entirely using them as discrete devices for switching power converters, so I won't be able to give much help talking about VLSI design.

Comment: @TimWescott Not usually, always. Except it's more proper to say it flows from body to drain or drain to body, if you want to be really specific.

Comment: No, this is not true. In VLSI design the body is not necessarily connected to the drain. MOSFETs are four-terminal devices.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The asker gave no indication that they were talking about VLSI until the comment on this answer, and I didn't want to bring that up as 1) it's not that useful for a beginner to know and 2) I don't know that much about it to begin with.

Comment: Well, for every discrete MOSFET in use there are about a million VLSI MOSFETs. So I think it is not prudent to assume that when someone asks about a "MOSFET" that they must be talking about discrete MOSFETs.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson This struck me as the sort of question a beginner would ask, and I strongly doubt a beginner would be working on VLSI design.

Comment: @Heath yes I was talking about VLSI, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson True.  But for every designer who deals in VLSI MOSFETs, there's got to be at least a thousand if not more designers who deal in discrete ones.

Comment: FWIW, My undergrad electronics course was fundamentally based on IC MOSFETs, and my other "first" exposure to MOSFETs in a college environment was in (transistor-level) CMOS logic gates. Had I no prior experience, then I *would not* have used discrete MOSFETs before "VLSI-style" MOSFETs.

Comment: @TimWescott Perhaps, but that doesn't change the fact that a MOSFET is **by definition** a four-terminal device.

Comment: The OP asked '**Can** Vds ever become[s] negative in mosfet?" - and the answer is yes, it  **can**, if the FET is eg. an asymmetric LDMOS or VMOS device. BTW bipolar transistors also work with Emitter and Collector swapped - but we don't say that an NPN Collector can never be more negative than the Emitter!

Comment: @BruceAbbott bipolar transistors are not symmetric, though. There is a clear and unambiguous distinction between the emitter and the collector: the emitter is much more heavily doped. (or is it the other way around, I can never remember....) If not for this asymmetry, it wouldn't be possible to achieve β greater than like two or something (again, i forget the specifics, but let's just say that any usable amplification requires asymmetric doping)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/302594/do-symmetric-bjts-exist